# Trying to get the other user but keep getting the current user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have this simple friendship model for users. I am trying to get the friends of the user that is currently logged in. Since friends means a relationship doesn't matter if you are user or friend I would like to get all the users that are not the current user.

The friendship model:

```
# WHEN A USER BECOMES FRIENDS WITH ANOTHER USER
class Friendship(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    friend = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="friends"
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["user", "friend"]
        verbose_name = "friendship"
        verbose_name_plural = "friendships"
        ordering = ["created_at"]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} is friends with {}".format(self.user, self.friend)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user == self.friend:
            return "Same person friendship should happen mentally"
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The function I am using to get the friends:

```
def get_friends(queryset, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs['user']
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    friends = [f.user for f in Friendship.objects.all().filter((Q(user=user) | Q(friend=user)))]
    return queryset.filter(user__in=friends)
```

I keep getting the logged in user as friend instead of the other users that are not the logged in user. What am I doing wrong here please?

If two people are friends then they are friends both ways. So with the following data:

users = {
id: 1,
id: 2,
id: 3,
id: 4,
id: 5
}

friendship = {
(user: 1, friend: 3),
(user: 2, friend: 1),
(user: 3, friend: 4),
(user: 3, friend: 5)
}

user 3's friends are user 1, user 4,  user 5

So return user 1, user 4 and user 5

Instead I get user 3, which is wrong

This seems really complicated but I simply want to return all friendship objects and if the user field is equal to the current user then return the user listed in the friend field and then obviously the other way around also. If the current user is listed in the friend field return the user in the user field.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the query to exclude the logged-in user so:

```py
def get_friends(queryset, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs['user']
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    friends = [f.friend for f in user.friends.all()]
    return queryset.filter(user__in=friends)
```

### Edit

Try to exclude the current user from the list of friends so:

```py
def get_friends(queryset, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs['user']
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    friends = Friendship.objects.filter(Q(user=user) | Q(friend=user)).exclude(user=user, friend=user)
    friend_users = [friend.user if friend.user != user else friend.friend for friend in friends]
    return queryset.filter(user__in=friend_users)
```

> **Note:** It is better to use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) as it calls `get()` on a given model manager, but it raises `Http404` instead of the model's `DoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work I get the logged in user and not the other users. id = kwargs['user'] is the logged in user.

Comment: @crawlingdev what's your problem can you please clarify again? What kind of queryset do you want?

Comment: @crawlingdev I think it should be `return queryset.filter(friend__in=friends)` it will give you all friends' instances from the `Friendship` model.

Comment: I want to return all the users in the friendship model that is not the currently logged in user. In other words return all users or friends where user 3 is either user or friend. Or better yet Friendship: user=6 friend=3 return user Friendship: user=3 friend=6 return friend

Comment: @crawlingdev Sorry but I'm still not understanding the queryset you want, can you provide some sample data with output in the question by editing?

Comment: Updated the question it is really a case of all friendship objects return all the objects where user 3 is either in user (column) or friend (column) but display the other user and not user 3

Comment: Thank you so much for trying. Unfortunately it now displays nothing BUT this: friends = Friendship.objects.filter(Q(user=user) | Q(friend=user)) returns the correct set of records all I want to do is display the user that is not the current user

Comment: I did not get the answer. I am still stuck at getting the user that is logged in and not the other user. The queryset is correct but I want the user not logged in

Comment: @crawlingdev The problem is that I am understanding your requirement, sometime you say you need a queryset with logged in user not the current user, then you are saying, but I also want the user not logged in, what is meant by all that? Can you provide some sample data instead in the question by editing after filtering from queryset and before queryset i.e. normal data from database.

Comment: There is data that I think explains it in detail. You and me are friends. Dinesh and me are friends. In the database for the first relationship (you and me) I am field user and you are field friend. In the next relationship (Dinesh and me) Dinesh is field user and i am field friend. Give me all users from friendship objects but give me the users that is not me. So give me you and Dinesh, but because You and Dinesh are different fields (You = friend, Dinesh = user) it is making things difficult I think